# Order of calling constructors in one case C++

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    A(){std::cout<<"A()"<<std::endl;}
};

template<typename T>
struct B
{
    A a;
    T b;
    B(){std::cout<<"B()"<<std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    B<B<B<int> > > Test;
    return 0;
}
```

The odrer of calling constructors is

```
A()
A()
A()
B()
B()
B()
```

And i have no clue why is that. I thought it would be A B A B A B. Could you explain me why?

Comment: Member variables are initialized before the constructor body runs.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually straight forward, if it was like A B A B A B, then you would have trouble if you wanted to access `b` from the constructor of `B`, since the order you thought implies that first member `a` gets instantiated, then `ctor` runs, then `b` gets initialized. In reality, every member is instantiated (constructed etc.) first, then, the constructors are called.

Answer (score 1):

This is because member variables must be initialized before the body of the constructor is executed. Consider the following example:

```
struct A {
    int value;

    // Here we explicitly initialize 'value' with 5
    A() : value(5) { }
};

struct B {
    A a;

    B()
    {
        // This is perfectly valid and would print 5,
        // because 'a' has already been implicitly initialized
        // with its default constructor.
        std::cout << a.value;
    }
};
```

If this weren't the case, what value would you expect `a` to have in `B`'s constructor? You'd run into all sorts of issues. Therefore, the default constructor of `A` must be implicitly called before the body of `B()`.

Essentially, to make it more explicit, this is what is happening:

```
    // Initialize 'a' before body of constructor
    B() : a()
    {
        std::cout << a.value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's analyze what you have here:

- you have an object `Test` of `class B<B<B<int> > >`, which is:

  ```
  class B<B<B<int> > > {
      A a;
      B<B<int> > b;
  };
  ```
- the second field of `Test`, `Test.b` is of `class B<B<int> >`, which is:

  ```
  class B<B<int> > {
      A a;
      B<int> b;
  };
  ```
- then you have the second field of `Test.b`, `Test.b.b`, which is of `class B<int>`, which is:

  ```
  class B<int> {
      A a;
      int b;
  };
  ```

so the order of initialization is:

- `A()` for `Test.a`.
- `A()` for `Test.b.a`.
- `A()` for `Test.b.b.a`.
- no constructor as `Test.b.b.b` is of type `int` and has no constructor.
- `B<int>()` for `Test.b.b`.
- `B<B<int> >()` for `Test.b`.
- `B<B<B<int> > >()` for `Test`.

Unfortunatelly, all the three constructors write on output the same thing: `B()`, but they're different constructors for different classes.

Comment: Yeah, but you're printing the opposite order, first is printed the most nested `b` field. The order might be `B() 2`, `B() 1`, `B() 0`.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. The order is B<int>(), B<B<int>>() ,... so the displayed numbers are correct: the first call to a constructor of a B<T> object to complete is B<int>(), hence B()0 is correctly printed first. The order  cannot differ at all, it's well defined.

Comment: Yes, but `B<int>()` is called for the deepest nested field, your level of nesting doesn't reflect the level of nesting in structure, just the nevel of type parameter nesting.

Comment: and that's just what I'm trying with this. b()0 says "a type called B was constructed which is of type B<T>, where T has 0 levels of nesting". I don't see a problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, because member initialization takes place before the body of the constructor. For realizing this, it is helpful to add the member initializers as well:

```
template<typename T>
struct B
{
    A a;
    T b;
    B()
    :
       a(),
       b()
    {
       std::cout<<"B()"<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

To fully grasp the order of execution, let's add a dummy integer field.
I also added a template to display the nesting. See http://ideone.com/KylQQb for a demo.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A
{
    A()
    :
    dummy(printf("Starting to construct A()\n"))
    {
        printf("Fully constructed A()\n");
    }
    int dummy;
};

template <typename T>
struct Nesting;

template <>
struct Nesting<int>
{
    constexpr static int value = 0;
};

template <template <typename> class T, typename I>
struct Nesting<T<I>>
{
        constexpr static int value = 1 + Nesting<I>::value;
};

template<typename T>
struct B
{
    int dummy;
    A a;
    T b;
    B()
    :
    dummy(printf("Starting to construct B() with nesting %d\n", Nesting<B<T>>::value)),
    a(),
    b()
    {
        printf("Fully constructed B() with nesting %d\n", Nesting<B<T>>::value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    B<B<B<int>>> Test;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this will be

```
Starting to construct B() with nesting 3
Starting to construct A()
Fully constructed A()
Starting to construct B() with nesting 2
Starting to construct A()
Fully constructed A()
Starting to construct B() with nesting 1
Starting to construct A()
Fully constructed A()
Fully constructed B() with nesting 1
Fully constructed B() with nesting 2
Fully constructed B() with nesting 3
```

Comment: I think your are a little confused.  Constructors don't begin to be called and in the middle other constructors are called.  Constructors are one threaded and serialized for one object to be fully constructed.

Comment: @LuisColorado I'm not confused at all. Maybe the naming isn't that great, but this is what's happening and what is defined by the standard.